# How to change a value inside array of object in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

I have stored an array of object in Redux State and inside each object there is a key named price. Now when I increment the quantity button I need to access the object that has the key inside redux and change the price value. I was able to do that but it's not working properly the price is being changed but a new object is being added in the state of Redux you can see it in the screenshot below. hope I was able to explain the problem clearly. if not please let know so I can explain more.

[image]

Cart Component

```
increment(e, item){
  let qty = e.target.previousElementSibling.textContent;
  qty++;
  e.target.previousElementSibling.textContent = qty;
  this.props.changePrice(item);
}

<div>
  <input onClick={(e) =>this.decrement(e)} type="submit" value="-"/>
  <span>1</span>
  <input onClick={(e) => this.increment(e, item)} type="submit" value="+"/>
</div>

function mapStateToProps(state){
   return({
     itemlist: state.rootReducer
   })
 }
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
   return({
      removeItem: (item)=>{
        dispatch({type: 'removeCart', payload: item})
      },
      changePrice: (item)=>{
        dispatch({type: 'changePrice', payload: item})
      }
   })
 }
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Cart);
```

Reducer Component

```
const changePrice = (itemArray, item)=>{
  let newObject = {};
  let filteredObject = itemArray.filter(reduxItem => reduxItem.id === item.id);
  let newprice = filteredObject[0].price + filteredObject[0].price;
  filteredObject[0].price = newprice;
  newObject = filteredObject;
  const something = ([...itemArray, newObject]);
  return something;
}
const reducer = (state = [], action) =>{
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'Add':
      return [...state, action.payload]
    case 'removeCart':
      const targetItemIndex = state.indexOf(action.payload);
      return state.filter((item, index) => index !== targetItemIndex)
    case 'changePrice':
         return changePrice(state, action.payload)
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
export default reducer;
```

Comment: You are mutating state object before copying with this line: filteredObject[0].price = newprice;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filteredObject` is an array. You override the `newObject` to be an array in this statement   `newObject = filteredObject`. So the `newObject` is an array ( in `[...itemArray, newObject]` )  rather than an object. Keep things simple without unnecessary complexity.You can use `Array.map`. So do this instead

```
const changePrice = (itemArray, item) => {
  return itemArray.map(reduxItem => {
     if(reduxItem.id === item.id){
       reduxItem.price = reduxItem.price + reduxItem.price
     }

     return reduxItem
  });
};
```

See this for more info https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#inserting-and-removing-items-in-arrays

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanx for reply but this will create a new object inside the state and I don't want that. I just want to change the price of the product

Comment: i'm actually new to redux and i dont if it's possible or not but what i want is not creating a new object i just need the price to be changed there is other ways using  localstorage but i thought there must be a way doing it in redux

Comment: @KinanAlamdar I got your point. Check my answer again....I updated the code

Comment: that's what i was looking for thanx brother so what was the issue can you explain if don't mind?  anyways thanx again for help

Comment: @KinanAlamdar Your welcome :)  .The issue was that you were returning the state with a new array with a new object `[...itemArray, newObject]`. So a new item was being added each time the price was changed.

Comment: @HemantParashar Correction. Even your solution returns a new Array. Reducer is always meant to return a new Array in redux world. 
OPs solution didn't work because he, quite clearly was adding a new object without complete understanding of spread operator.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of mutating the state.

```
// use this
const newState = Object.assign({},state);
```

We can create a new state and now if you do this, this works fine.
This avoids mutating state.